Can't include file or directory in php (Warning: require_once(../layout/): Failed to open stream)
I tried to include a file from another directory, but I get a warning.
I want to load my master page file

And no css or JS file loads into my project.
I tried:
 <?php require_once '../layout/header.php';?>
    
  <h1>Wellcome, Guest</h1>

  <?php require_once '../layout/footer.php';?>
    


We can't see your filesystem, so we don't know where your included files are really located, relative to the file being executed.  Read this to help you: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

you can use magic function DIR to include your file. example:
require_once __DIR__ . 'layout/header.php'; 

OR my suggestion:‌
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/layout/header.php';

